Docker Compose: The "Hh" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string
I recently dockerized my Next.js application. Everything works so far but every time I docker compose up, I receive these weird warnings about variables that I never used and are nowhere to be found:
docker-compose up
WARN[0000] The "Hh" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "xG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "Hh" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "xG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Running 3/2
 ✔ Network hey-shop_default       Created                                                0.0s 
 ✔ Container hey-shop-postgres-1  Created                                                0.1s 
 ✔ Container hey-shop-web-1       Created                                                0.0s 
Attaching to postgres-1, web-1

This is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U postgres -d postgres'"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - VERCEL_TOKEN=${VERCEL_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5555:5555
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres-data:

My Dockerfile:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install --global vercel@latest

COPY . .

ARG VERCEL_TOKEN
RUN vercel env pull .env --environment=Development --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN

RUN DISABLE_ERD=true npx prisma generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma

ENV POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

This is my .dockerignore:
node_modules
.next
.swc
.env

I work on an Apple M chip and dockerize using Ubuntu 20
I tried completely purging the containers and rebuilding but this appears every time. I don't know if this is something that will give me trouble down the road or if I can ignore it. Either way it seems like something doesn't work as it should.

Check your .env file for values containing dollar signs

Does docker-compose config show any of the unwanted environment variables, probably coming from a file you did not mention in your question ?

Thanks to Hans and AymDev, this oversight from me was quickly resolved.
I had in fact a secret set in .env that contained the mentioned "variables":
JWT_SECRET="[...]$Hh[...]$xG[...]"

As I pull the secrets using my Dockerfile, I could remove the entire .env and the warnings disappeared.

(I'd generally avoid trying to put secrets in your image.  They'll be there in plain text for anyone who has the image and docker inspects it, and you'll need to rebuild the image if you ever change the password or the deployment mechanics.)

Thanks for the hint, David. So if I got you right, you would not recommend doing RUN vercel env pull .env --environment=Development --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN in my Dockerfile. What is best practice to pull envs then? Should this be part of the docker-compose or be pulled from another place entirely?
